# how to access the values of a json in java

Tags: java, json

```
[{
    "year": "2017",
    "org": "1",
    "sub_org": "",
    "sub_org_amt": ""
}, {
    "year": "2017",
    "org": "1",
    "sub_org": "",
    "sub_org_amt": ""
}]
```

This a sample data from my ajax request from :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add.jsp',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        action: action,
        tabledata: JSON.stringify(tabledata)
    },
    success: function(data) {


    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("error" + data);
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
    },
    complete: function() {
    }
})
```

How can i access each value in `add.jsp` so that i can insert them in database

I tried

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(tabledata);
```

I have `import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"` but i get error in `JSONParser`

`UPDDATE`

Added this line `import ="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser"`

But when i do `out.println("[" + json.toString() + "]");` nothing is shown

Comment: Post the error please.

Comment: @Aubin pls see update

Comment: Instead of parsing it as `JSONObject`, try parsing it as `JSONArray`.

Comment: you can also use jackson to convert json array to object and on the opposite side https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/.

Comment: @BrownmanRevival Post the error.

Comment: @Ravikumar sorry no more error sir after adding the `import ="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser"`

Comment: Try printing tabledata on the Java side. I suspect it's an empty string

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use jackson library to do what you're trying to do.

I assume you are using servlet to handle the add.jsp page so in your servlet , add those imports after adding the jackson library in your package

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

then add in doPost method, the method to convert the received json from the add/jsp :

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    /**
     * Convert json to object
     */
    // 1. get received JSON data from request
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    String json = "";
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        json = json + line;
    }

    #object mapper to map the json to the class
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    # object converted by json
    Object object = objectMapper.readValue(json, Object.class);

}
```